# Transaction not active in child method of ApplicationContext

Tags: java, transactions, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I can only get an active programmatic transaction in my `spring (3.0.5) jdbc application`, running on `Oracle 11.2`, 
when the `txAdvice` points to the actual method `(mainTest())` called from the application context `(example "AAA" below)`.
If the `txAdvice points` to a child method `(transactionTest())` of `mainTest() (example "BBB" below)` then I no longer have an active transaction.

Relevant code:

```
public class MainDS {
    public static Controller cont;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] configList ={"spring.xml"};

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configList);
        cont = (Controller)ctx.getBean("controller");
        cont.mainTest();     
    }
}

public class Controller {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

    public void mainTest()
    {
        transactionTest();
        // MainDS.cont.transactionTest(); // also does not work
    }

    public void transactionTest(){
        try {
            // This prints "Transaction active = true" for AAA but "Transaction active = false"  for BBB
            System.out.println("Transaction active = " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() );

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

and my spring.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">


<bean id="controller" class="Controller">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>


<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="main*" propagation="REQUIRED" />       <!-- AAA -->
        <tx:method name="transaction*" propagation="REQUIRED" />    <!-- or BBB -->
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>



<aop:config>    
    <aop:pointcut id="myMethods" expression="execution(* *..Controller.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myMethods" />
</aop:config>



<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="2" />

    <property name="url" value="my connection details" />
    <property name="username" value="xxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

How do I get an active transaction for option BBB.
Any ideas very welcome.

Regards
DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BBB" case: the "mainTest()" method calls directly the "transactionTest()" method, omitting the aspect.

If you want to invoke the dynamically created proxy of the "transactionTest()" method, I suppose, you could do it through self bean reference (injected). Also as far as I remember, the spring manual used to suggest to call such methods via interface references (again using injected interface references).

**Note: this is a really bad design!** Implementation example (per request):

```
<bean id="controller" class="test.Controller">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
    <property name="instance" ref="controller" />
</bean>

public class Controller {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private Controller instance;

    public void mainTest() {
        instance.transactionTest();
    }

    public void transactionTest() {
        System.out.println("Transaction active = " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() );
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public Controller getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setInstance(Controller instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
}

Transaction active = true
```

This behaviour is well documented in the spring manual (I recall it in the Aspects section), so you should definitely read it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html section 9.6.1

More over, this question has already been covered here: [One Service method invoke inner multiple method for Spring transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231220/one-service-method-invoke-inner-multiple-method-for-spring-transaction?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link, its similar to what im doing but not the same. They want 2 transactions ie 
    <tx:method name="insertA" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    <tx:method name="insertB" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" /> 
what I want is all methods in the Controller() class begining with trans* to be in their own transaction. Can you please explain how to do "self bean reference"

Comment: I changed the call to transactionTest() to:
MainDS.cont.transactionTest();
to use the ApplicationContext, but there was still no transaction  in transactionTest()

Comment: Thats what i suspected you meant and i agree , it's bad design. I tried it however since im stuck, but it didn't work, still no transaction. I think that:
    MainDS.cont.transactionTest(); 
should probably be the solution but that also doesn't work but i don't understand why not.

Comment: Hm, are you stuck with 3.0.5? You should try upgrading to the latest spring 3 release and see results. May be you've missed something obvious, but both solutions do work with the latest spring on my PC. And ofc. I wouldn't exclude some bug / specifics of the 3.0.5 version.

Comment: I've tried 3.0.5 - both solutions do work. Double check everything.

Comment: I've also tried 4.0.6 and it doesn't work. I've been double checking everything for several days, im sure i've done something stupid but i just can't see what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61279/discussion-between-ivan-and-ds).